# WSO2 IS Server Start Error - A child container failed during start java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException due to NumberFormatException

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

When I try to start WSO2 IS I can see the below error.

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-12-05 21:31:08,401] [] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase} - A child container failed during start java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [TenantContextRewriteValve[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.service.ExtendedStandardService.startInternal(ExtendedStandardService.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat.start(CarbonTomcat.java:113)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.ServerManager$1.run(ServerManager.java:167)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [TenantContextRewriteValve[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:176)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "300ms"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityConfigParser.buildCacheConfig(IdentityConfigParser.java:278)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityConfigParser.buildConfiguration(IdentityConfigParser.java:177)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityConfigParser.<init>(IdentityConfigParser.java:74)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityConfigParser.getInstance(IdentityConfigParser.java:81)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.getContextsToRewrite(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:134)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.startInternal(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 20 more
```

The error log indicates that there is a string `300ms` is passed instead of a number. What are the steps that I can follow to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when one of the configurations you have set up is passing `300ms` instead of `300`.

Usually, all the unit resolving configurations are at `<IS_HOME>/repository/resources/conf/unit-resolve.json` file and since you have not added a configuration there you are getting the above error.

You can use the following steps to identify the place that you are having the error.

1. Go to `<IS_HOME>/repository/resources/conf/default.json` file and check for any configuration that has the value `300ms`.
2. At there you will find that the only key value pair having the default value of `300ms` is `"cache.default_timeout":"300ms"`
3. Now check for any references where the above key is used at the `default.json` file.
4. You can see that, that `cache.default_timeout` has been used at several places like `cache.authentication_context_cache.timeout, cache.authentication_request_cache.timeout, ...`
5. Next, find the place that the above keys are applied at the `.j2` template.
6. In the above case, you can see that the keys `cache.authentication_context_cache.timeout, cache.authentication_request_cache.timeout, ...` are used at `identity.xml.j2` file with the following config.

```
<CacheManager name="IdentityApplicationManagementCacheManager">
            <Cache id="framework_session_context_cache" name="AppAuthFrameworkSessionContextCache"
                   enable="{{cache.framework_session_context_cache.enable}}"
                   timeout="{{cache.framework_session_context_cache.timeout}}"
                   capacity="{{cache.framework_session_context_cache.capacity}}"
                   isDistributed="false"/>
....
</CacheManager>
```

7. Since you have found the exact template where the keys which use the `300ms`, go to the file which reflects the template configurations in `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf` directory.
8. In the above case, its `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/identity/identity.xml` file. (because `identity.xml.j2` is the template for `identity.xml` file)
9. Check for the value `300ms` in that file and you will notice a configuration similar to the following.

```
<Cache id="authentication_error_cache" name="AuthenticationErrorCache"
   enable="true"
   timeout="300ms"
   capacity="5000"
   isDistributed="false"/>
```

10. Now we know the exact place we are getting the above error.

To solve the above error, you can take two approaches,

##### ***Approach 1 - Configuring the timeout value using `deployment.toml` file***

Although this is not the approach that you should use, if you put the below configuration after identifying the correct XML tag which is causing the error, the issue will be solved.

For the step 9's case we can see that we should configure the timeout of `authentication_error_cache`.

To do that, you can put the following configuration in `deployment.toml` and restart the IS.

```
[cache.authentication_error_cache]
timeout=300
```

##### ***Approach 2 - Configuring the timeout unit in `unit-resolve.json` file***

The reason for above error is because the `authentication_error_cache` unit resolve config is missing from the `unit-resolve.json` file.

You can simply add the unit responsible for the issue to the `unit-resolve.json` file and the issue will be solved.

For the above case, you can add the following to the `unit-resolve.json` file.
`"cache.authentication_error_cache.timeout": "ms",`